# jquery how can i return a moved unordered list item back to its original position in the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

so im working on a mobile menu and what i want to have happen is for the user to click on a list item and have that item move to the top of the list, then when the user clicks another item it moves the first item back to its original position and the second item up into the first position.
so im stuck on the second part and im not sure how to execute it. i've tried storing the list in an array and adding and removing items with splice, but i couldn't get it to work properly, any help would be great thanks.

```js
$(".article-featured__navigation-menu-mobile li").click(function(){
  var item = $(this).addClass('active-state');
  $(".article-featured__navigation-menu-mobile").prepend(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="menu-item active-state"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" >0</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="1">1 </a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="2">2 </a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="3">3 </a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="4">4 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, given the markup that you have, what about it tells you, after it has moved, what it's original position was?

Comment: @Taplar sorry i was still making edits, but im stuck on the second part and i was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as far as how i should be thinking about the issue

Comment: Well, you could always throw a data field on them to tell you what their original position was.  Like `data-index="3"` or whatever.  Then regardless of which one moves, you know where it came from and can put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** and take advantage of the `order` *property* which specifies the layout *order* of *flex-items* inside *flex-containers*. In other words, you can manipulate *element's order* regardless of the their *position* in the *DOM*.

I've also made some corrections to *jQuery* to give you the desired result:

```js
$("ul li").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active-state').siblings().removeClass('active-state');
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks them vertically (assuming the mobile menu layout) */
  list-style: none;
}

.active-state {
  order: -1; /* the initial value of the order property is set to 0, i gave it -1 because of the changed direction, otherwise it would have been 1, i.e. place it above the others because of the higher value */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" >Link 0</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="1">Link 1 </a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="2">Link 2 </a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="3">Link 3 </a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="4">Link 4 </a></li>
</ul>
```